# Compare DateDiff issue

Tags: vbscript

I need to compare 2 dates to find out if a computer is EOL or very EOL. Different kind of text is depending on if it is a EOL or VEOL.

Current date is 29-08-2016
Ex. 1 lstrValue = 31-12-2016 = 4
Ex. 2 lstrValue = 31-07-2016 = -1

```
select case DateDiff("m",Date,CDATE(lstrValue))
    case 1, 2, 3
        bEOL = true
    case else
        bVeryEOL = true
end select
```

The problem in my exampel is that if DateDiff is either 4, 5, 6, ect the bVeryEOL is true. That is not what I'm looking for. I'm only looking for bVeryEOL is true, if the datediff is negativ

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something like this, then:

**EDIT:** Changed the code because previous was not valid VBScript

```
Dim strResult : strResult = DateDiff("m",Date,CDATE(lstrValue))
Select case strResult
    Case 1, 2, 3
        bEOL = true
    Case Else
        If strResult < 0 Then
            bVeryEOL = True
        Else
            'add logic
        End If
End select
```

Comment: Not legal VBScript.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Thank you for pointing that out. I confused it with VBA. I've edited my code